# Making summary details element auto collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-lists

I've been trying out the summary and details list and can't find a way to make it auto collapse when the next in the list is clicked...

Here the code I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
                    <header class="major">
                        <h2>Stuff I do</h2>
                    </header>
                    <p>Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet vulputate.</p>
                    <ul class="alt">
                        <li>
                            <details><summary><span class="icon major fa-camera-retro"></span>
                            <h3>List item 1</h3><p>Donec accumsan interdum nisi</p></summary>
                            <p>Aliquam ante ac id. Adipiscing interdum lorem praesent fusce pellentesque arcu feugiat. Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet integer vulputate phasellus lorem ipsum dolor lorem magna consequat sed etiam adipiscing interdum.</p></details>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <details><summary><span class="icon major fa-pencil"></span>
                            <h3>List item 2</h3><p>Donec accumsan interdum nisi</p></summary>
                            <p>Aliquam ante ac id. Adipiscing interdum lorem praesent fusce pellentesque arcu feugiat. Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet integer vulputate phasellus lorem ipsum dolor lorem magna consequat sed etiam adipiscing interdum.</p></details>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <details><summary><span class="icon major fa-code"></span>
                            <h3>list item 3</h3><p>Donec accumsan interdum nisi</p></summary>
                            <p>Aliquam ante ac id. Adipiscing interdum lorem praesent fusce pellentesque arcu feugiat. Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet integer vulputate phasellus lorem ipsum dolor lorem magna consequat sed etiam adipiscing interdum.</p></details>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <details><summary><span class="icon major fa-coffee"></span>
                            <h3>List item 4</h3><p>Donec accumsan interdum nisi</p></summary>
                            <p>Aliquam ante ac id. Adipiscing interdum lorem praesent fusce pellentesque arcu feugiat. Consequat sed ultricies rutrum. Sed adipiscing eu amet interdum lorem blandit vis ac commodo aliquet integer vulputate phasellus lorem ipsum dolor lorem magna consequat sed etiam adipiscing interdum.</p></details>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
details summary::-webkit-details-marker {
display: none;}

summary:hover {
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff200;
```

}

So when 'list item 1' is opened and 'list item 3' is clicked I want item 1 to automatically collapse again. Help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Idea

1. On load, `slideUp()` all paragraphs inside `li`, so only headers are visible.
2. Attach click handler on each header, so once clicked, it `slideUp()` all other items, and `slideDown()` the clicked one.

### Implementation

Alter html to add clases so `jQuery` can reference them (`class="click"` and `class="collapsable"`):

```
<li class="click">
  <details><summary><span class="icon major fa-coffee"></span>
    <h3>List item 4</h3><p>Donec accumsan interdum nisi</p></summary>
      <p class="collapsable">Aliquam ante ac id. Adipiscing interdum lorem praesent fusce pellentesque arcu feugiat.
```

jQuery onload:

```
$('.collapsable').slideUp();
$( '.click' ).on( "click", function() {
    $('.collapsable').slideUp();
    $('.collapsable', this).slideDown();
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mbs4wxp/4/

---

### EDIT

To solve the issue described in comment:

> The content is fairly long in some list items, so when next one is
>   clicked and previous collapses it sometimes leaves you at far below
>   the clicked content.

Chain the `animate({scrollTop...` to the `slideDown()` event so your clicked div is scrolled to the top of the screen. You just need to alter your jQuery a bit:

```
$('.collapsable').slideUp();
$( '.click' ).on( "click", function() {
    $('.collapsable').slideUp();
    $('.collapsable', this).slideDown().promise().done(function(){
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 100}, 200);
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mbs4wxp/6/

Comment: This works great so far, thanks! Just one more issue to address:

The content is fairly long in some list items, so when next one is clicked and previous collapses it sometimes leaves you at far below the clicked content.

Tried to solve it with making entire heading a link and give id to content but that left me nowhere...

Comment: Let me clarify; I have several <p> elements so I wrapped it in a div tag making a 

<div class="collapsable"><p>etcetera</p><p>etcetera</p><p>etcetera</p><p>etcetera</p><p>etcetera</p></div>

So first div is very long in content... scroll down to end and you click on next div... it collapses back up and lots of content disappears upwards, so you need to scroll back up to see the beginning of it... Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: That seems to work pretty neat! Thanks again... just one more thing with it; (also in your link to fiddle) When you followed the first list item and then the second and wan to click the first one again, it doesn't open on the first click but just becomes sort of 'active' and requires another click. Not terrible, just a minor hickup :) Let me know if you know the solution... for now at least we are good to go live with the site!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure JavaScript solution, try this:

Put this function in the  of your document:

```
function thereCanBeOnlyOne(elementId) {
  var detailsElements = document.getElementsByTagName('details');
  for (var i=0; i<detailsElements.length; i++) {
    if (detailsElements[i].id != elementId && detailsElements[i].classList.contains('collapsible')) {
      detailsElements[i].removeAttribute('open');
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your HTML:

1) use the class of 'collapsible' and put an id attribute on the details

2) add the onclick handler to the summary.

```
<details id="one" class="collapsible" open=true>
<summary onclick="thereCanBeOnlyOne('one');">One</summary>
```

For a demo see: https://waxphilosophic.sdf.org/webdev/accordian/summary-details-js.html

You can simplify even further if you don't care about marking only certain summary/details as collapsible.